# Django : notifications refresh automatically

Tags: django, django-signals

I created a notification system adapted to my website and it's works. When a user is on home page, he can see his notifications.

But currently, for refresh his notifications the user have to reload the home page... (currently notifications visibles only on home page)

I want the notifications refresh automatically where there is a new notification, so without reload the page.

I want also user can be alerted by a new notification in all pages of my website (example : a div appears with notification 
message).

**How can I do this ?**

Thank you !

*PS : My Notification is very simple, so a Notification model with a Manager.*

Comment: I guess this can be done in front end -- javascript things; for instance, repeatedly checking a server using ajax (also the web api for this check needed) and `setInterval` js function.

Comment: I don't know js api can do this... Have you example of these api ?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably look at websockets. Check this out [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html.)

I dont know how you have setup your notification system, but making the use of websocket with combination of javascripting is way to go in my opinion.